# Can objects of a view controllers dissappear for input in previous view controller

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7

I am new to ios programing please help. 
I am taking input via alert in previous view controller and then I want make objects I.e.couple of. Buttons from Group of buttons appear or dissappear based on selection of user. As it happens for Android activity objects. Visibility gone or appeared.Thanks in advance

Comment: In general, you'll get better, more useful responses here if you show your code.

Comment: alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Customer", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
           let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("customerVC") as UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
/*THIS IS CODE FOR ONE ACTION OF ALERT*/

Comment: in the same way i have coded for other action both are executing perfectly

Comment: but now when user click on any one of action i.e. CUSTOMER or other alert AGENT.the new view  controller that appears i want the objects i.e. the buttons to appear dynamically depending upon the user action

Comment: in more simpler words can a couple of buttons be displayed from a group of buttons as it happens for (ANDROID i.e. VISIBILITY GONE OR APPEARED)

Comment: Please edit your code into your question rather than post it as comments